# Synchronizing threads in list

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I know there are many questions treating thread synchronization but no one has quite given me an explanation of how I can use it in my implementation. So I have a Server that wait for clients to connect, as on connection a thread is created for each client that connects, each message is sent from each one of the clients will display in the server with the clientIP>>  and each client will then retrieve this message from the server so each client has the same messages. Similar to mIRC one might add..

okay so to the problem:

I am keeping a session instance of each client that gets connected in a linkedlist.

My session class is very simple:

```
public class Session extends Thread{
    private Socket soc;

    public BufferedReader in;
    public PrintWriter out;

    public Session(Socket in_client){
        //soc = new Socket();
        soc = in_client;
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream(), true);

            String inputLine;

            while(true){
                if((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    textArea.append("Client IP["+soc.getInetAddress()+"]: " + inputLine+"\n");

                    for(Session s:dstruct)
                        s.out.println(s.soc.getInetAddress()+">"+inputLine);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }catch(IOException e ){
            try {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }}
    }

}
```

In the Server threads run method I create sessions and push them to the datastructur linkedlist through:

```
while(true){        
    if((clientSocket = serverSocket.accept())!=null){
        dstruct.push(new Session(clientSocket));
    }
```

Now how would I get theses threads synchronized? I've read on many different suggestions like
calling synchronized(...) or having synchronized in the method declaration, also read on notifying but can not get my head around what this accomplishes when notifying the threads, 
where would I put this in this case?
I have a Server thread checing for clients connecting them to sessions that are extended by Thread. Should the main thread synchronize the child threads or should the child threads have som synchronized method that somehow synchronize them?

Comment: You show where you add the Session to the list, but where do you start the thread for it?

Comment: You must be refering to the main thread it is started in main method,

Comment: Server class has a main method that starts thread then it jumpsto the run method hope that clarifies, the child threads are started in the constructor of session.

Comment: Please format your post properly (look at how the code is formatted), this will give you a better chance to have a meaningful answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to make sure that when `Session` reads from `dstruct` it can see all the `Sessions` that the `Server` has put in the list? The easiest thing to do would be to use the classes from `java.util.concurrent`, such as a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.

Try defining `dstruct` as `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Session>`.

Comment: Well I don't know what would that accomplish? I need basically the threads to be syncronized, would that do it?

Comment: I must not be understanding the question correctly. What do you mean by the threads being synchronized?

Comment: Syncronized threads is a pretty usual thing, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: I know what synchronization is, but if `dstruct` is a thread-safe collection then why would you need any additional synchronization?

Comment: Ok, well its a school assignment and one of the demands is to have synchronized threads, so thats what im tryin to find out, right now Im not sure so Im going for both the concurrent list and declaring synchronized methods for push and deleting from the list, you are saying its enough with the concurrent list?

Comment: I *think* that it would be enough, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of synchronizing threads is to ensure that operations on any data shared by the threads are done *atomically*, to ensure the consistency of the data as seen by the threads. The effect of synchronizing, in a synchronized block or method, is that the first thread to enter that block will acquire a lock on the monitor associated with the synchronized object. All other threads that subsequently request that lock, by entering the same or another synchronized block/method on the same object, will have to wait until the lock is released, which happens whenever the initial thread exits the synchronized block.

In your case, the shared data is the LinkedList dstruct, this is the object for which you need atomicity on all operations. Thus, in the code you showed, you need to synchronize in two places:

In the Session's `run()` method, you need to synchronize the entire `for` loop:

```
synchronized(dstruct) {
  for (Session s: dstruct)
    s.out.println(s.soc.getInetAddress()+">"+inputLine);
  }
}
```

In the Server's `run()` method, around the `push()` operation:

```
if ((clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()) != null) {
  synchronized(dstruct) {
    dstruct.push(new Session(clientSocket));
  }
}
```

By googling "java thread synchronization" you will find a lot of material and learning resources on this topic, like [this one](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076971/java-concurrency/how-the-java-virtual-machine-performs-thread-synchronization.html). I'm pretty sure you'll find something out there that will make things clear to you.